# How to construct a NodeSeq programmatically?

Tags: xml, scala

I have a NodeSeq like this

```
val article_template =
 <div>
      <div class="title"></div>
      <div class="content"></div>
      <!-- some other markups don't know -->
 </div>
```

I want to create this structure for each article in a List (defined as `val articleList`), resulting in this:

```
 <div>
      <div class="title">title a</div>
      <div class="content">content a</div>
      <!-- some other markups don't know -->
 </div>
 <div>
      <div class="title">title b</div>
      <div class="content">content b</div>
      <!-- some other markups don't know -->
 </div>
...
```

**Updated**:

Please note the `<!-- some other markups don't know -->` part,
so I cannot use XML literal syntax to construct it.
I need a list of modified `article_template` with corresponding article info.

Comment: If you don't want to construct XML in code, then you may consider creating a template. Scalate can help you with this: http://scalate.fusesource.org/

Comment: You are not being clear enough in this question. Or, rather, the question is clear enough, but when people answer it you imply there are further requirements not stated here. Please revise the question to get answers more adequate to your needs.

Comment: Is it permissible to include any old additional junk in the output?  This certainly meets your requirement of not knowing what it is...

Comment: @Kevin Wright Yes~ I need the part of unknown markup. It's in a val. I need to pattern match that val, and modify it and then put it into a List. I don't quite familiar with Scala, don't know how to write that.

Comment: @Daniel C. Sobral I noticed that you have a very great answer on a very similar question, I hope you can also answer my question.

Comment: @Sawyer watch out your markup, html5 have an article tag for this semantic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See scala.xml.transform._ and the corresponding Stack Overflow questions.

It will probably look somewhat like this:

```
import scala.xml._
import transform._

case class Article( title: String, content: String )

val articleList = List(
    Article("title 1","content 1"),
    Article("title 2","content 2")
)

class TransformArticle(title: String, content: String) extends RewriteRule {
  override def transform(n: Node): Seq[Node] = n match {
    case div @ <div/> => div match {
        case elem: Elem if elem \ "@class" contains Text("title") =>
            elem copy (child = Text(title))
        case elem: Elem if elem \ "@class" contains Text("content") =>
            elem copy (child = Text(content))
        case other => other
    }
    case other => other
  }
}

val article_template =
 <div>
      <div class="title"></div>
      <div class="content"></div>
      <!-- some other markups don't know -->
 </div>

Group(
    articleList.flatMap( article => {
        new RuleTransformer(new TransformArticle(article.title, article.content)) transform article_template
    })
)
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel, this is what I want. You always give excellent answers.

Answer (score 3):

This is something [lift](http://liftweb.net/) is really good for

```
import net.liftweb.util.Helpers._ 

case class Article( title: String, content: String )

val articles = List(
    Article("title a","content a"),
    Article("title b","content b")
)  

val snipet =
"article *" #> articles.map { article =>
    "header h1 *" #> article.title &
    ".content *" #> article.content
}

val article_template =
<article>
    <header>
        <h1>Title</h1>
    </header>
    <section class="content">
        Content
    </section>
</article>

snipet( article_template )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Group](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/xml/Group.html) to group XML elements. In XML literal it will look like this:

```
val xml =
  <xml:group>
    <div>
      <div class="title">title a</div>
      <div class="content">content a</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="title">title b</div>
      <div class="content">content b</div>
    </div>
  </xml:group>
```

#### Update

You can create XML dynamically like this:

```
case class Article(title: String, content: String)
val articles = List(Article("A1", "A1 content"), Article("A2", "A2 content"))

val xml =
  <xml:group>{articles map { a =>
    <div>
      <div class="title">{a title}</div>
      <div class="content">{a content}</div>
    </div>
  }}</xml:group>
```

#### Update 1

Here is another variation using template. Template is just a function that returns XML. In this case I using currying in order to produce list of templates for each article (that still needs some stuff to be provided):

```
case class Article(title: String, content: String)
val articles = List(Article("A1", "A1 content"), Article("A2", "A2 content"))

def articleTemplate[T](article: Article)(stuff: T) =
  <div>
    <div class="title">{article title}</div>
    <div class="content">{article content}</div>

    <div class="stuff">{stuff}</div>
  </div>

val allArticles = articles map articleTemplate

val allArticlesWithStuff: NodeSeq =
  allArticles.zipWithIndex map {case (f, i) => f(i)}
```

Comment: I wanna create this structure for each article in a List dynamically.

Comment: @Zwcat: can you look at Update 1. Is this something that you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `Article` is defined something like:

```
case class Article(title: String, content: String)
```

and `articleList` as:

```
val articleList = List(
  Article("title a","content a"),
  Article("title b", "content b"))
```

You could produce the XML fragment with:

```
val xml: scala.xml.NodeSeq = articleList map { article => 
  <div>
    <div class="title">{article.title}</div>
    <div class="content">{article.content}</div>
  </div>
}
```

Comment: Actually the markup for article is really large, and I don't wanna to construct it in literal.

Comment: Please be more specific, how do you intend to supply the list of article properties that should be included as elements in the output?

Answer (score 0):

Use flatmap to add them together like this:

```
val xml: NodeSeq = List("Test", "Something", "Yo").flatMap(s => <a>{s}</a>)
```

- With articles instead of just strings of course

**Update**: Works well with matching as well

```
val xml: NodeSeq = List("Test", "Something", "Yo", 1).flatMap{
  case s: String => <string>{s}</string>
  case i: Int => <int>{i}</int>
}
```

Comment: It would be fine if the xml is only simple as `<a>{s}</a>`. actually, the html structure for my actual problem is very large. I need a way to pattern match the attribute i wanna modify.

Comment: Sorry, I need to convert a List[Article] to List[NodeSeq], the structure of the NodeSeq is as I described in the post, you're not doing XML pattern matching.